# Error (Status 402) (Request req_QPLfwLnwBf2OeY) Your card has insufficient funds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

Using Rails 5.02, Ruby 2.3, with Stripe gem 'stripe'

My code for the deduction of the charge is as:

```
     begin
    # Use Stripe's library to make requests...
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer => 1234,
        :amount => 100, ## i.e 1$
        :description => "job payment",
        :currency => 'usd',
        capture: false,
        metadata: {'transaction' => transaction_id},
    )

    if !charge.review
      charge.capture
    end

    if charge.paid?
      @job_payment.invoice_id = transaction_id
      @job_payment.transaction_date = Time.now
      @job_payment.save
      @job.update(job_payment_status: 'paid', expiry_date: Time.now + 30.days)
      puts 'Job Payment.....'
      job_payment_done_email(@job, @job_payment.invoice_id)
    end

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = "Insufficient funds!"
    Rails.logger.info '***********Begin Exception*********'
    Rails.logger.info e
    Rails.logger.info "Amount = " + @amount.to_s
    Rails.logger.info '***********End Exception*********'
  rescue Stripe::RateLimitError => e
    # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
    flash[:error] = "Too many requests made to the API too quickly!"
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
    flash[:error] = "Invalid parameters were supplied to payment gateway!"
  rescue Stripe::AuthenticationError => e
    # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
    flash[:error] = "Payment authentication problem!"
  rescue Stripe::APIConnectionError => e
    # Network communication with Stripe failed
    flash[:error] = "Payment can not be completed due to the network problem with payment gateway!"
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
    # yourself an email
    flash[:error] = "Something went wrong inside server while payment in stripe!"
  rescue => e
    # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
    flash[:error] = "Something went wrong inside server while payment!"
  end
```

The transaction get stuck by giving the following error of insuficient balance:

> (Status 402) (Request req_QPLfwLnwBf2OeY) Your card has insufficient
>   funds.

Instead if the amount was less than the desired one, then it should have told that at the js pop up itself, but it is giving this error on the server end, But the card has an amount of Rs 1000 in it already.